Does this rollup script build a correct types.d.ts file, given that when the NPM package is imported it returns an error?
I'm trying to package a React component, written in Typescript, to release it open-source on NPM.  This is the repo, which contains all files related to the project:
https://github.com/lightenna/react-mermaid-diagram
Issue
When I import the component from NPM (as-is):
import {MermaidDiagram} from "@lightenna/react-mermaid-diagram";

I get this error when running in Jest:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I suspect this is because I've incorrectly packaged it with rollup, such that Node doesn't get the correct entity.
Background
types.d.ts file referenced in package.json as "types": "dist/types.d.ts"
import React, { MouseEvent } from 'react';

interface MermaidDiagramProps {
    children: string;
    id?: string;
    testId?: string;
    className?: string;
    onClick?: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
    onError?: (error: any) => void;
}

declare const MermaidDiagram: (props: MermaidDiagramProps) => React.JSX.Element;

export { MermaidDiagram };

The component is exported as a constant:
import {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import mermaid, {RenderResult} from 'mermaid';
import {MermaidDiagramProps} from "./MermaidDiagram.types";
import React from "react";

const MermaidDiagram = (props: MermaidDiagramProps) => {
    const [element, setElement] = useState<HTMLDivElement>();
    const [render_result, setRenderResult] = useState<RenderResult>();
...
}

export { MermaidDiagram };

Tests
The component is tested with Jest/RTL in MermaidDiagram.test.tsx.  I tried importing the component locally:
import {MermaidDiagram} from "@/components/notes/MermaidDiagram";

which worked and proved to me that the React Component is fine.  I tried importing from NPM:
import {MermaidDiagram} from "@lightenna/react-mermaid-diagram";

which resulted in this error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I also tried importing as if it were the default:
import MermaidDiagram from "@lightenna/react-mermaid-diagram";

which also returned an error, as expected:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Also tried
I did try to export it as the default:
export default function MermaidDiagram(props: {
    children: string,
    id?: string,
    className?: string,
    onClick?: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void,
    onError?: (error: any) => void,
}) {
    const [element, setElement] = useState<HTMLDivElement>();
    const [render_result, setRenderResult] = useState<RenderResult>();
...
}

but that yielded a near-empty types.d.ts:
export { };

I think because of a missing setting.  I found this SO issue, which is similar, but I couldn't resolve my problem.
Configuration
I've worked extensively on the rollup.config.js and tsconfig.ts setup files, but not succeeded in working out what is wrong with the export.

Did you already resolve this? I couldn't reproduce the issue on the Stackblitz

No, not to my knowledge.  I don't understand how your excellent Stackblitz demo is working without error.

Now this is a bit of a wild guess here, but do you have circular dependencies? Potentially cause by some symlink in dev or something?

Also are you using vite on consumer? try deleting node_modules/.vite

This StackBlitz shows the package imported into a Next.js project.  Now the problem here is different, in that I think it's using CJS, which is trying to require() mermaid, which needs to be imported.  I'm now trying to set up rollup to only export an ESM version.
I'm not seeing circular dependencies.  My module has a peer dependency on React and Mermaid, but you can see in my package.json that I've imported both.

The StackBlitz demo is now working correctly.  I've stripped out the CJS config from rollup, so it's just packaging ESM.  The only problem that persists is the original Jest error.  I'll try to replicate that in a sandbox.

Ive got a feeling, the source of your original error is to do with esmExternals option. mermaid is an ESM package. Unless you configure this option to include mermaid (even if the top level rollup config  has externals set), it treats it as commonjs and that has the consequence that default imports from that module act differently.  You touched on similar a couple of comments up.

@adsy yes I think you're right.  I've now stripped out the CJS config, which gave me the confidence to release it on NPM.  I read this (https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/import-esm-externals) and I wonder if it's being changed in my transpiler config for Jest.
